# How to use the switch command with a search bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4.5, uisearchbar

I have a table view programmed with the data below. It also has a working search function programmed onto the page. I am trying to use the 'switch' system to transfer to a specific view controller depending on what cell is pressed.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

smtArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [Smt SSSOfCategory:@"P" name:@"HW"],
                    [Smt SSSOfCategory:@"P" name:@"WI"],
                    [Smt SSSOfCategory:@"P" name:@"WC"],
                    [Smt SSSOfCategory:@"P" name:@"C"],nil];
```

//Code for the search function

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
Smt *smt = nil;


if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    smt = [filteredSmtsArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"One" sender:self];
            break;

        case 1:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Two" sender:self];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

}
```

Currently I am stumped on how to perform a segue based on the object within the tableview cell. Obviously at the moment the segues are dependent on the indexPath.row which is useless for a searchable table. (I am aware that the segues currently only work when the data is filtered).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *content = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

        if ([content isEqualToString:"One"]) [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"One" sender:self];
        else if ([content isEqualToString:"Two"]) [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Two" sender:self];        
    }
}
```

in your method. And then you can get whatever you want from it.

Comment: Hi Iblue, thanks for the response. Sorry if this is a novice request, but could you be more specific with your answer? 

Where are you implementing that code in the method, and specifically how are you using it to activate a segue depending on what object is in the cell? 


I'm still pretty stumped... 
Thanks for your time,

Comment: @user2019029 does this answer your question?

Comment: Iblue, you are a genius. I can't tell you how long this has been driving me nuts for. Thank you so much. 

As soon as I reach 15 reputation I will vote up your answer. 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you use "One" , "Two" ... as identifier , why do not use your smtArrays objects name as identifier ? If you afraid the identifier is deplacate , you can use SSSOfCategory + name . And your code will be perfect and more readable

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Smt *smt = nil;


    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        smt = [filteredSmtsArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:smt.name sender:self];

    }

}
```